# Understanding ActiveRecord::Relations with RSpec example

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rspec-rails, relation

I have the following ROR RSpec test:

Keep in mind that the test does pass as is in the code below. The method is correctly defined and does what is intended. The question is why when I modify and remove the [] around the @public_topic in the second example the test fails?

```
describe "scopes" do
    before do
      @public_topic = Topic.create!(name: RandomData.random_sentence, description: RandomData.random_paragraph)
      @private_topic = Topic.create!(name: RandomData.random_sentence, description: RandomData.random_paragraph, public: false)
    end

    describe "visible_to(user)" do
      it "returns all topics if user is present" do
          user = User.new
          expect(Topic.visible_to(user)).to eq(Topic.all)
      end
      it "returns only public topics if user is nil" do
        expect(Topic.visible_to(nil)).to eq([@public_topic])
      end
    end
  end
```

**update**

```
scope :visible_to, -> { where(public: true) }
```

Comment: What is your `visible_to` method supposed to return. From your test, it looks like it is supposed to return an array with something in it. Hence when you take out the `[]`, returning an object, it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to say without seeing the implementation of `visible_to`.

From the first example, it looks like that method returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object. That is going to represent a collection of objects and not a single object.

So, in essence, it comes down to:

```
object != [object]
```

Comment: Even if its a single object inside of the collection it does not count as a single object?

Comment: Nope. Think of it like this: A parking garage with a single car inside of it is not equivalent to a single car.

Comment: you could also do `expect(Topic.visible_to(nil).first).to eq(@public_topic)`